# Ember: Dynamically add a record to array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a page where I want to let user enter multiple records. For example, let's say I have a page where user can enter as many as Student record he wants, where each Student record contains fields like name, age, etc.

Currently, I have a button on the page which calls a method on a controller.

```
// controller/studentlist.js
actions: {
    createStudentRecord() {
        let student =  this.get('store').createRecord('student', {});
        let model = this.get('model') || Ember.A();
        model.pushObject(student);
        this.set('model', model);
    }
}
```

I initially fetch the model like this:

```
// routes/studentlist.js
model(params) {
    return this.get('store').query('student', { orderBy: 'class_id', equalTo: params.class_id });
}
```

Then, I iterate over the `model` in my template so when the model gets updated, the list also gets updated.

```
// templates/studentlist.hbs
{{#each model}}
    // Show list of students
{{else}}
    <p>No students.</p>
{{/each}}
```

However, when I do this, I get `internalModel.getRecord is not a function`.

Googling lead to this on github. https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3530, which seems to be the exact same issue I have. However, I don't quite get what I am supposed to do to get this scenario working. Could someone guide me to properly implement this?

I tried doing `this.set('model', model.toArray())`, but this didn't help.

Comment: Hmm, that should work, did you try a `{{#each model as |student|}}` in your template?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, Seems like I didn't think enough. I only had to fetch the model in a different way.

```
// routes/studentlist.js
model(params) {
    return this.get('store')
        .query('student', { orderBy: 'class_id', equalTo: params.class_id })
        .then((students) => { return students.toArray(); });
}
```